# Disable sharing of files through Public link

Tags: files, winter19

In winter 19 release, salesforce came up with sharing files to anyone(those who has view access) using "Public Link" option. However, I don't want this option to be visible/enabled for my users.

Can you please let me know how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5):

These permissions are controlled in the permission sets.

To check what permission sets have this feature enabled go setup and navigate to "Permission Sets" and click on the "System Permissions" section.

[image: Step One]

Once the page has loaded scroll to where it says "Create Public Links" and either tick to enable the permission or disable.

[image: Step Two]

Bonus tip! Using the Keyboard shortcut( CTRL + F or CMD + F) for most of these kinds of situations where you need to find a specific keyword in order to find the thing are looking for, can save you a ton of time.

Answer (score 1):

You can removed public link from setup and find "content deliveries and public link".
From there you will be able to remove "public link" in files.